# Efficient way to add months to a numeric YMD format?

Tags: sql, netezza

I'm currently busy with some SQL (in both Netezza and HiveQL). Our company often uses numerical fields for dates (e.g. 20150602 for date, 20160400 for month).

I need to add 6 months to one of these dates, and usually I would do:

```
cast(to_char(add_months(to_date(A.date,'yyyyMMdd'),6),'yyyyMMdd') as int)
```

Although this isn't pretty, it works and I don't know any shorter or better way. My main problems is that this is a large table (12 billion rows) and date conversion isn't exactly snappy, and the query I'm working on is getting killed due to running to long. Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: what's the datatype of those fields? and which version of Hive are you on?

Comment: This is not an Hive code

Comment: @Dudu: You're right, its Netezza. The issue is still the same.

Comment: @Vamsi: Datatype is int. Hive version is 1.2.1000.2.5.3.0-37

Comment: Hive related tags removed. If you want to ask an Hive related question open a new post for it.

Comment: `SELECT DATEADD(M,6,'20160602')` result `2016-12-02 00:00:00.000`

Comment: What do you mean by "date conversion isn't snappy?"  I typically find it to be quite snappy.  Are you changing the date with an UPDATE or a CTAS?

Comment: @ScottMcG: I mean it's relatively slow, as in versus integer arithmetic. I'm starting to think I won't be able to get around converting it to a date though, so I'm gonna try and look at some other optimizations earlier in the query.

Comment: I think you're right that there's no way to avoid conversion, either explicit or implicit, but I do this sort of conversion all the time, and even on an old twinfin single rack it's not something I worry about at all.  But, context matters, too.  Are you looking to do the add_months as part of ETL or is it part of a BI query or ... ?

Comment: Im doing feature generation for a machine learning model. The things is, I want to join a really large table to another one based on events being within a 6 months time period of a date. The join is probably also a decent part of the slowdown tbh. Now that you mention it, would the join by date inequality be slower than a join on integer inequality?

Comment: I'd wager that you're right.  It's more the inequality join slowing you down than any sort of type conversion.  Netezza stored dates and integers under the covers as integers, and they hash/compare with similar efficiency, so that's ok.  The  mandatory Nested Loop Join you get with joining on an inequality will be much slower than the optimal/usual hash join.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try a join to a time dimension table with these columns (ALL int):

`MonthId StartDate EndDate
1       20150101  20150199
2       20150201  20150299
3       20150301  20150399
.
.
.
24     20161201  20161299`

Then do this if you simply want the first day of the month as a result (will need a different timetable if you want to join-convert the full date, but this example is easyer to write on an iPad and can be to expanded):

```
select 
  t2.startdate, 
  y.* 
from yourtable y
Join timetab t1
  on y.dateAsInt between t1.StartDate and t1.EndDate
Join t2 
  On t1.monthid=t2.monthid-6
```